# global namelist is not defined. Is only module variable

Tags: python, variables

Ok so using this code I ran some testing to see what the main problem was. I found there is a problem with the phone number input validation so i #'ed it ,so its inactive.(if your are able to fix that problem wil lgive you a sticker.
Anyway:

```
def main():

    name = []
    phone = []
    groupno = []
    score = []
    review = []

    q = input('Do you wish to Continue Y/N')
    while q != "Y":


        def data(name, phone, groupno, score, namelist, groupsizes,phonumber, mealscore):

            name =  input("Please enter the customer's name.")
        namelist.append(name)

        #phone = int(input("Please enter the customer's Phone Number."))
        #if len.str(phone) == 11:
        #    else: phone = int(input("Please enter the customer's Phone Number."))
        #phonumber.append(phone)

        sizeofgroup = int(input('Please enter the size of group: '))
        while sizeofgroup < 1 or sizeofgroup > 20:
            sizeofgroup = int(input('Please enter a valid group size: '))
        groupsizes.append(sizeofgroup)



        score = int(input('Please enter the rating of the meal: '))
        while score <= 1 or score >= 10:
            score = int(input('Please enter the rating of the meal- between 1 and 10: '))
        mealscore.append(score)

main()
```

And i get this error:

> Do you wish to Continue Y/N?: y Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "\QRSTORAGE\SMCPupilData$\stirlim\Work\S5\Computing\Coursework
>   Task\Program\code2.py", line 35, in  main() File
>   "\QRSTORAGE\SMCPupilData$\stirlim\Work\S5\Computing\Coursework
>   Task\Program\code2.py", line 16, in main namelist.append(name)
>   NameError: global name 'namelist' is not defined

Not sure what the error means but ofc its something to do with declaration of variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Python uses indentation for scoping, the assignment `namelist` has to be indented to line up with the assignment to `name`. Otherwise it is in the scope outside the function, and there is no variable called `namelist` there. A more helpful error message would be "line needs to be indented", but there's no way for Python to guess that.

Also, `len.str(phone)` fails because it tries to get the `str` attribute of `len`, and it hasn't got one. You mean `len(str(phone))`.

Comment: Thanks dude the namelist section works^^.Unfortunately the phone stuff does not atm but ty for trying ^^

Comment: Actually it is not about identation but about function definition. Python does not use identation for scoping. try to define a variable inside an if block: `if True: my_var=10; print(my_var)` will work ;)