# Lack of Positional Arguments error

Tags: python, position

I'm testing my code and I get this error:

```
Please enter the customer's name: 1
Please enter the customer's Phone Number:01506890639
Please enter the size of group: 2
Please enter the rating of the meal: 4
Do you wish to continue: Y/N?n

The largest group that visited had a cohort of:2

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\CWtsk\code2.py", line 107, in <module>
    main()
  File "E:\CWtsk\code2.py", line 13, in main
    mealrating(name, phone, groupno, score, review)
TypeError: mealrating() takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given
```

Code until this point

```
def main():
    name = []
    phone = []
    groupno = []
    score = []
    review = []
    q="y"


    data(name, phone, groupno, score, q)

    maxi(groupno)
    mealrating(name, phone, groupno, score, review)
    poorest(name, phone, groupno, score, review)

def data(n, p, g, s, q):
    while q != "n":
        name =  input("Please enter the customer's name: ")
        n.append(name)

        phone = ""
        while len(str(phone)) != 11:
            try:
                phone = input("Please enter the customer's Phone Number:")
            except ValueError:
                phone = ""
        p.append(phone)


        groupno = int(input('Please enter the size of group: '))
        while groupno < 1 or groupno > 20:
            groupsizes= int(input('Please enter a valid group size: '))
        g.append(groupno)



        score = int(input('Please enter the rating of the meal: '))
        while score < 1 or score > 10:
            score = int(input('Please enter the rating of the meal- between 1 and 10: '))
        s.append(score)

        q=input("Do you wish to continue: Y/N?")

#finding largest group size
def maxi(groupno):

    xGroup = groupno[0]
    for x in range(0,len(groupno)):
        if groupno[x] > xGroup:
            xGroup = groupno[x]
    print('\n')
    print('The largest group that visited had a cohort of:' + str(xGroup))


#determining the meal rating and counting number of applied ratings and priniting
def mealrating(score):
    for x in range(0,len(score)):


        if score[x] >= 1 and score[x] <= 3:
            review[x] = poor
            p = p + 1

        if score[x] >= 4 and score[x] <= 6:
            review[x] = good
            g = g + 1


        if score[x] >= 7 and score[x] <= 10:
            review[x] = excellent
            e = e + 1

    print('\n')
    print("The customer rated tonight's meal as:")
    print('%10s' % ('Poor:', p ))
    print('%10s' % ('Good:', g ))
    print('%10s' % ('Excellent:', e ))
```

Comment: You are giving 5 arguments to the function `mealrating` but this function only takes one: `score`

Comment: Also in the `mealrating` function you have `review[x] = good`. `good` isn't defined anywhere so it will throw an error. You need to change that to `'good'`. However I suspect you would want to keep the ratings so you don't even need that, you can just count them the way you already are.

Comment: You seem to be [really](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251373/global-namelist-is-not-defined-is-only-module-variable) [struggling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297916/fielding-numbers-using-and-values) [with this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252958/python-input-validate-with-string-length). Perhaps you need to take a step back and break the problem down into smaller parts, e.g. separating the different types of data entry (name, phone number, group size, rating) so you can test each separately. Also, note that `maxi` is simply `max(groupno)`.

Comment: Thanks guys. So many silly mistakes x)